# Javascript: Increment count by 5 for a variable inside a setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to use [Google Analytics events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) to track time spent on site more accurately (without relying on delta time between visits to another page on site). I'm using `setInterval()` to continuously trigger that GA even every 5 seconds. How do I properly increment seconds elapsed to send along with the GA event data?

```
  var count = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    // increment "count" by 5 each time setInterval is run
    ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var count = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    // increment "count" by 5 each time setInterval is run
    count+=5; //is this what you need?
    ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
var count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  count = count + 5;
  // increment "count" by 5 each time setInterval is run
  ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    count+=5;
    // increment "count" by 5 each time setInterval is run
    ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I gather this correctly, but we can do this like:

    `var count = 0,interval=5000;
      setInterval(function(){
        // increment "count" by 5 each time setInterval is run
        ga('send', 'event', 'time', 'tracking', 'seconds', count+interval);
      }, interval);`

In clear interval you can set count = 0 again.