# Create a number sequence function that runs on a timer

Tags: javascript

I need to take a number (ex. 100), then in 10 seconds add 100 to it. In another 10 seconds, add 100 again to create a running total.

How would I create a function to keep a running total, and have it on a timer that fires every 10 seconds?

Comment: You could use class and generators https://jsfiddle.net/suqbn6fd/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment integer by 1; every 1 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586890) and [Javascript: Increment count by 5 for a variable inside a setInterval() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942872/javascript-increment-count-by-5-for-a-variable-inside-a-setinterval-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `setInterval`

Here in eachInterval function it calls the function (given in setInterval ) and add the value to total and display in console. You can pass time in function as per you need

```js
let total = 100;
let interval;
function eachInterval(time){
  interval = setInterval(()=>{
    total+=100;
    console.log(total)
  },time)
}

setTimeout(()=>{
  clearInterval(interval)
},5000)

eachInterval(1000)
```

Comment: OP looks like a newbie, this may have a lot more than they can chew at once things like arrow notation, ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createsequence(){
  var number = 100;

  console.log(number)

  //setInterval run at gap of 10 secs use it instead of timer
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      //increment number
     number += 100;
     console.log(number)
  },10000);

//10000ms is 10 secs
}

createsequence()
```